# h2 make a computed column based on present column in table

Tags: h2

I have a very strange problem, to my opinion, I wish to make existing column as computed basing on present column in the same table. The existing column type is "DATE", the other one - "Datetime". I use query " ALTER TABLE TEST ALTER COLUMN 'date' AS CONVERT('last_date', DATE) ". 
Always I got the exception: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "ALTER TABLE TEST ALTER COLUMN 'date'[*] AS CONVERT('last_date', DATE)"; expected "identifier";...

Waiting for any idea.

Comment: Try using double quotes instead of single quotes.

Answer (score 3):

The [H2 SQL grammar for alter table](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#alter_table_alter) is different. Try:

```
drop table test;
create table test("last_date" timestamp, "date" timestamp);
alter table test alter column "date" timestamp 
    as convert("last_date", date);
```

or

```
drop table test;
create table test(last_date timestamp, date timestamp);
alter table test alter column date timestamp 
    as convert(last_date, date);
```